# How to build working public folder in Gatsby framework? I mean, if I open index.html, I should be able to access entire website

Tags: html, reactjs, gatsby

I am willing to generate Gatsby website but I need to deploy this in an on-premise app. So technically I need to put the public folder and link the index.html wherever I want. But, when we generate build, the index.html doesn't show the whole website. Is there a way I can make it work?

In Gatsby freamework, we usually say npm run develop and test our website on localhost:8000. Now let's say npm run build so that build will generate.

But I want to use the index.html as full functional website like we generally do with any website development in an older way of HTML and CSS.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: I know, old question, but have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how the `index.html` file is written, sometimes it’s not sufficient to open the file locally in a web browser—this can be true even if you’re not using Gatsby. Instead, sometimes it still needs to be served by a web server.

What I imagine you’re seeing is that the `index.html` page works, but then some of the links are “broken” because they don’t point to the right places in the context of just opening the `index.html` file in your browser, but they actually will be correct in the real context of having the static site served by a web server.

To make that easier, Gatsby has a build-in command for serving an already built site. After running:

```sh
gatsby build
```

…in the terminal and it completes, run:

```sh
gatsby serve
```

Now Gatsby is serving the flat HTML, CSS, and JavaScript version of your project from the `public/` folder at `http://localhost:9000` for you to view. You can view source in the browser to see that this is the compiled result of your HTML file. Hope that’s helpful!

Comment: Yes. That's the same case. Index.html works fine but others don't. Gatsby serve is working fine. But the challenge is I need to deploy this website into an internal application which is an on-premise solution. So having a web server is not an option for me.